# Contact form 7 - adding text field to drop down menu

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Anyone have any idea how to add text field to menu item upon selecting "others"

I have below field in form and want to display a text field to fill when someone select " others".

Select Your Country ( Required)
[select* Country first_as_label "Select you country?" "ABC" "XYZ" "RST" "Others"]

Comment: Check this [wp-conditional-contact-form-7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/)